# Boost finding error compiling Mongodb C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost

I am compiling the Legecy Mongo drivers (1.0.0), and it says it cannot find boost libraries even though I can see the files there,

Using gcc 4.4.6

```
pdsf6 $ scons --cpppath=/.../sw/boost_1_57_0 --libpath=/.../sw/boost_1_57_0/stage/lib --prefix=/.../sw/mongo-cxx-driver --sharedclient
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons version: 2.3.4
python version: 2 6 6 'final' 0
Checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
Checking whether the C compiler works... yes
Checking if C++ compiler "g++" is GCC... yes
Checking if C compiler "gcc" is GCC... yes
Checking if C compiler supports -Wno-unused-local-typedefs... no
Checking if C compiler supports -Wno-unused-function... yes
Checking if C compiler supports -Wno-unused-private-field... no
Checking if C compiler supports -Wno-deprecated-declarations... yes
Checking if C compiler supports -Wno-tautological-constant-out-of-range-compare... no
Checking if C compiler supports -Wno-unused-const-variable... no
Checking if C compiler supports -Wno-missing-braces... yes
Checking if we are using libstdc++... yes
Checking for libstdc++ 4.6.0 or better... no
Checking if we are on a POSIX system... yes
Checking if the POSIX monotonic clock is supported... yes
Checking for __thread... yes
Checking for gcc __atomic builtins... no
Checking for useable __sync builtins... yes
Checking for C++ header file boost/version.hpp... yes
Checking for C++ library boost_regex-mt... no
Checking for C++ library boost_regex... yes
Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mt... no
Checking for C++ library boost_thread... no
can't find boost
```

It actually finds the libboost_regex, but not thread!

The `/.../sw/boost_1_57_0/stage/lib` folder has libboost_thread.so.. can anyone help me figuring why this doesnt work? Please!

Comment: check if CMakeLists.txt available. use cmake instead.